# Compiler doesn't see function, thougth all other functions, used in the same way, are seen

Tags: c++, friend-function

I have three files: matrix.cpp main.cpp matrix.hpp.
In matrix.hpp a function str_matrix(const char*) is declared, its text is in matrix.cpp. In main.cpp I want to use this function.
In matrix.hpp:

```
class matrix {
...
  friend matrix str_matrix(const char*);
```

In matrix.cpp:

```
#include "matrix.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
...
matrix str_matrix(const char* a) {
...}
```

In main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "matrix.hpp"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
...
matrix m1(str_matrix ("{1}"));
```

But I have a mistake:

```
nirvana@lpt00:~/cpp/matrix$ g++ main.cpp matrix.cpp 
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:12:30: error: ‘str_matrix’ was not declared in this scope
   matrix m1(str_matrix ("{1}")); 
                              ^
```

What shall I do to manage with it?

Comment: Did you try `matrix m1(str_matrix ("{1}"));` inside any function scope?

Comment: It was written in main(). When I used this function inside matrix.cpp (I didn't used main.cpp, it was main() inside matrix.cpp), all was ok.

Comment: as @M.M's answer says, you are missing a definition of the friend function actually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you have the same problem as in this smaller example:

```
class matrix {
public:
    friend matrix str_matrix(const char*);
};

matrix m1(str_matrix ("{1}"));
// error: 'str_matrix' was not declared in this scope
```

The problem here is that a `friend` declaration does NOT make the declared name available for lookup in the enclosing scope.  The name is only available for argument-dependent lookup, however ADL does not find the function here because the argument has type `char *`, not `matrix`.

To fix this you need to include a non-friend declaration as well, e.g.:

```
matrix str_matrix(const char *);
```

after the class definition in the header.

Comment: Would it be fair to say `friend matrix str_matrix(const char*)` is not declaring the function at all, merely saying that function _is_ a `friend`, but please look elsewhere?

Comment: @John not really, it does declare the function but with different lookup rules to a non-friend.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@M.M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36216481/1413395) using the current c++ standard you can inline the `friend` function definition:

```
class matrix {
...
  friend matrix str_matrix(const char*) {
     // Provide the friend unction definition here 
  }
};
```